# How to get a list of all commits in github repos for given person

Tags: github

I would like to get a list of all commits that were done by a person in github.

Is it possible to do globally without the repos?

Currently I can do this https://github.com/some/repo/commits/master?author=some_nick for each repo (some/repo, other/repo, another/repo etc.) that the user might have committed code.

But I would like to have something like:
https://github.com/commits?author=some_nick
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

How about https://github.com/user?tab=activity? It does show the commits from all of the repositories but it also shows forks, pull requests, stars or comments. I know you may want to see less information, but I don't have any idea which is closer to the question than this. However if you want to track a person, this is handy enough (at least for me).

Comment: Yes, but it shows only activity in the recent year and also I have to click on the boxes to see the activity (and it doesn't need to be a commit).